# Android GCM notifications drains battery

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I'm using Urban Airship and GCM to send push notifications to my app, GCM setup required process wake lock permissions in manifest,

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  application can keep the processor from sleeping when a message is received. Optional—    
  use only if the app wants to keep the device from sleeping
```

When i checked my app battery performance with PowerTutor it shows a continuous process on my app.
is this WAKE_LOCK causing the issue.

Comment: Did it show which process on your app was running continuously? How do you know it is even related to GCM?